# WPF combining MouseDown and TouchDown to same event

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, mouseevent

I am developing an app which will be used on a laptop with touch screen. Hence MouseDown events are essentially doing the same action, how should this be done.

The code I have written something like this -

XAML

```
<Button MouseDown="Button_OnMouseDown" TouchDown="Button_OnTouchDown"/>
```

C#

```
private void Button_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Action();
}
private void Button_OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Action();
}
private void Action()
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make eventArgs to be more generic one. Use `EventArgs` in place of `MouseEventArgs` and `TouchEventArgs`.

```
private void Button_OnMouseDownOrTouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action();
}
```

and now you can hook to same event from XAML:

```
<Button MouseDown="Button_OnMouseDownOrTouchDown" 
        TouchDown="Button_OnMouseDownOrTouchDown"/>
```

That's called **Contravariance on delegates**. Read more about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx).

> Delegates can be used with methods that have parameters of a type that
>   are base types of the delegate signature parameter type. With
>   contravariance, you can use one event handler instead of separate
>   handlers. For example, you can create an event handler that accepts an
>   EventArgs input parameter and use it with a Button.MouseClick event
>   that sends a MouseEventArgs type as a parameter, and also with a
>   TextBox.KeyDown event that sends a KeyEventArgs parameter.

Comment: I get a resharper warning - `Incorrect method signature` for using `EventArgs` instead of `TouchEventArgs` for TouchDown event handler. Its fine for `MouseDown`. Its not a big deal, but would like to hear your suggestion

Comment: I personally never rely on Re-Sharper. (If you search online, you will find flood of posts regarding re-sharper showing warning for perfect scenarios in code.) I have no idea that it shows warning for TouchEventArgs but not for MouseEventArgs.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for clarifying

Comment: As it seems this does not work (anymore? .Net 4.5 at least) - WPF throws a XAMLParseException, which says it cannot bind to the target method, since its signature isn't compatible to the delegate type.

Comment: No, it definitely works in 4.5 as well. Contra variance was never removed from any .Net framework.  Also tried in small sample and works perfectly fine for me. Please raise separate question with your sample to have better picture of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion - the problem was apparently caused by the control in question being a `UserControl` (which a colleague created instead of using a real button). I'm still not sure why the error happens, but I'll think about it and maybe post a new question.

Comment: The param EventArgs could be InputEventArgs, then you'd be able to set the 'Handled' property.