# wpf touchdown vs mousedown

Tags: wpf, touch

In my application user can use touch and also a mouse.
I am listening for mousedown event:

```
obj->ImageContainer->MouseDown += ...
```

But there is a different behaviour when I click either I tap.
In the click handler there is a complex function.
Click works good, the touch tap stucks the application.

I can't understand why.
If I also  listen for touchdown event - both of them called.
Anybody have an idea what may be a difference between both?

Thank you

Comment: There's a reasonable explanation of the behaviour of touch events here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692286/WPF-and-multi-touch . You could try the approach from here to force the same behaviour for mouse/touchdown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399502/wpf-combining-mousedown-and-touchdown-to-same-event .

Comment: Touch events are converted to Mouse events in WPF if they are not handled, eg `e.IsHandled = true`.

Comment: @Sheridan, But I still not understand the difference. Could you tell me that? thanks.