# MouseLeftButtonDown event not fire while Touching the WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom control which inherits from Control and I'm trying to trigger MouseLeftButtonDown using Touch on WPF platform.The event MouseLeftButtonDown does not fire while touch the window but its works fine when use mouse device. I have tried the related PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event also nothing happens while touch the window. 
Please suggest me the solution.
Regards,
Jeyasri M

Comment: What about the [Touch..](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/touchdown/) events?

Comment: Show your XAML and c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Already in another post
[WPF combining MouseDown and TouchDown to same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399502/wpf-combining-mousedown-and-touchdown-to-same-event)

Anyway have a look to this, maybe can help...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/12/07/wpf-touch-basics/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My requirement is not using any separate touch event. “For an example Grid. MouseLeftButtonDown event get trigger while touch and also by mouse left button down”, I want same to be work in my custom control. For me CustomControl. MouseLeftButtonDown not trigger while Touching. Please share any idea on this.