# Popup not closing on touch

Tags: wpf, popup, touch

I have a WPF popup which works perfectly using a mouse.

The popup will close when the user clicks outside the popup as expected - all is good so far

When on a touch screen the popup refuses to close until another control gains focus (for example by clicking a button or focusing a textbox)

What do I need to do to get the popup to close on touch like it does on click?

I assume it has something to do with not losing focus on touch but I cant find anything on google relating to this

Thanks

Comment: "The popup will close when the user clicks outside the popup as expected" - outside the popup, how is this implemented? It seems the popup listens for an event to close on? You know there are seperate events for mouse and touch in WPF right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399502/wpf-combining-mousedown-and-touchdown-to-same-event

Comment: Yes this is using the in-built functionality of the popup, I set the popup to StaysOpen = False which allows it stay open until someone clicks outside

Comment: So, it does dissappear when you 'touch' a textbox? I have no touch enabled device, so cannot test, but maybe you can manually listen for the event with TouchDown and reset focus?

Comment: I am not saying there is buggy code, or even that I have a problem with my code. I am merely asking whether WPF focus changes happen differently between touch and mouse inputs. A question need not have code if it is not asking to diagnose a problem with specific code

Comment: are you using windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I have just launched this code:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="50" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Show</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right">None</Button>
        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" Width="200" Height="100" IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="False" >
            <Border Background="Red" Width="50" Height="50" ></Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>


private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

and it works properly even if I use touch device (on currently newest Windows version). You could have some other issues in your code, but to answer your question:

> I am merely asking whether WPF focus changes happen differently between touch and mouse inputs

No, it does not. Please check my simple code or check if your application works ok on other touch device. Maybe you are handling touch events somewhere by your self?

Answer (score 0):

I have to confess that I have not tested the solution proposed by Jonathan Dragon.

I've come to this question while searching for a solution to a similar issue (perhaps). To be able to show tooltips on some items in a touch interface we listen for the MouseUp and TouchUp events of the item, and in that case shows a Popup containing the tooltip information.

We use an attached property to set up the tooltip and the popup is reused with different content, for all items using this feature.

I experience that if I open the Popup and then close it by clicking a blank space - things work as expected.

If I open the Popup and then click a Button (something with a Command), the popup does disappear, but all the buttons do not respond until I open the Popup again and close it by clicking a blank space.

I was just reading up on the "StaysOpen" property of Popup, and well...

> false if the System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup control closes when a mouse or keyboard event occurs outside the System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup control. The default is true.

It does not mention touch events specifically, while keyboard and mouse events are.
This COULD indicate that the popup might not react the same for touch events.